# Google Maps API non-minified/obfuscated

Tags: google-maps

Does Google provide non-minified / non-obfuscated versions of their various javascript API's?

For example, I'm using their LocalSearch control and getting a cryptic error "a is null". Setting a breakpoint in Firebug is not very helpful because I'm 3 levels deep in minified code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a non-obfuscated version of the API (it isn't an open source project).  If you post a link to the page in question, we might be able to help debug the issue?

I have seen the "a is null" message many times and each time have been able to track down the issue eventually.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there isn't a way to get the original version with real (helpful) variable and comments since it's not open source

But! There's a new(ish?) feature in Google Chrome Dev Tools where you can de-minify code ("make minified code human readable")

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format

[image: screenshot of human-readable feature in chrome dev tools]

should at least help a bit with debugging